# Singleton in Ruby without using Singleton module or class variable

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, singleton

When I need a singleton class in my Ruby code (for example, single logger for multiple classes) I usually use code like this:

```
class Parent_Singleton
  @singleton = nil

  def self.new
    @singleton || (@singleton = super)
  end
end
```

This approach allows me to avoid using the module `Singleton` (because I don't want to use a special method `instance` to get an object of this class, I just want to use the usual `Parent_Singleton.new` in any part of my code to get my singleton object).

Another advantage of this approach is the ability to avoid using class variables `@@singleton` which of course is a [bad practice](https://rubystyle.guide/#no-class-vars) because of its behavior in inheritance. My code doesn't have this issue:

```
class Child_Singleton < Parent_Singleton
end

p1 = Parent_Singleton.new
p2 = Parent_Singleton.new
c1 = Child_Singleton.new
c2 = Child_Singleton.new

p1 == p2 # => true
c1 == c2 # => true
p1 == c1 # => false
p2 == c2 # => false
```

If I need to store some variable data in my class, it's also not a problem:

```
class Parent_Class
  @singleton = nil
  @some_data = ''

  class << self
    def new
      @singleton || (@singleton = super)
    end

    def some_data
      @some_data
    end

    def some_data=(value)
      @some_data = value
    end
  end
end

class First_Child_Class < Parent_Class
end

class Second_Child_Class < Parent_Class
end

Parent_Class.some_data = 'Parent'
First_Child_Class.some_data = 'First_Child'
Second_Child_Class.some_data = 'Second_Child'

puts Parent_Class.some_data # => Parent
puts First_Child_Class.some_data # => First_Child
puts Second_Child_Class.some_data # => Second_Child
```

So my question is: if this code is bad, what's wrong with it? If this code is good, why the most of the examples worldwide suggest using either `Singleton` module (with `instance` method) or class variable-based singleton classes instead?

Answer (score 4):

The Singleton module in Ruby for instance also guarantees synchronised access, e.g. if multiple threads try to create an instance your implementation would not work.

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/singleton.rb#L112-L168

It's also a convention (in other programming languages too) to call the method `instance` or `getInstance`. Calling several times `new` and always getting the same instance seems not very accurate.

I'm not sure I understand the use case of storing data beside the object rather than in the actual object.

Btw: In Ruby, classes are spelled in CamelCase and not Snake_Case.